# mysql_query update with indeterminate number of parameters

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I have an update.php file, calling a function which is on "functions.php" in order to update info.

I would like to know if there is a way to make a unique function for Updating, which would work independently on the number of arguments needed for it.

I know one way of doing this, which is, on the php file, saving the entire query on a variale first and then sending it to functions.php with the variable as parameter, as seen on here:

PHP file:

```
$queryUpdate="UPDATE carta SET titulo='$titulo', ingredientes='$ingredientes', precio='$precio', tipo='$tipo', porcentaje='$porcentaje', imagen='$rutaFinal' WHERE id_carta='$id'";
$update = consultaQuery($queryUpdate);
```

FUNCTIONS file:

```
function consultaQuery($par_query){
$consulta = mysql_query($par_query);
return $consulta;}
```

But I was wondering if there is another way of dinamizing my function to send any $variables=values separately in order to be added to a mysql_query(UPDATE) query.

I could do this by:

PHP file:

```
$update = consultaQuery($titulo,$ingredientes,$precio,$tipo,$porcentaje,$rutaFinal,$id);
```

FUNCTIONS file:

```
    function consultaQuery($par_titulo,$par_ingredientes,$par_precio,$par_tipo,$par_porcentaje,$par_rutaFinal,$par_id){
$consulta = mysql_query(UPDATE carta SET titulo=$par_titulo, ingredientes=$par_ingredientes, precio=$par_precio, tipo=$par_tipo, porcentaje=$par_porcentaje, imagen=$par_rutaFinal WHERE id_carta='par_id);
return $consulta;}
```

But this would not work, for example, with a 3-argument update. Is there any way of making this? Do I keep doing this as the first way? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: http://ro1.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: **WARNING** You are using a deprecated version of MySQL that is wide open to SQL injection and attack. Please update your code to use the `mysqli_` extensions and syntax.

Comment: Alternatively you could pass an array as an argument.

Comment: @Mihai that was a great clue. I'll try to solve this with func_get_args, hope I'll be able. Thank you PlantTheIdea. John, that option is contemplated on the last part of the question.